# Error in setwd - cannot change working directory

Tags: r

Can anybody help me how to resolve this error?

> Error in setwd("C:\Users\user\Downloads\Vendor_Data") : 
>     cannot change working directory

```
data <- read.csv("Vendor_Data")
```

Comment: Check your access permissions.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are trying to change the working directory to a file, not a directory. Try instead:

```
setwd("C:\Users\user\Downloads")
```

and then explicitly mention the file extension:

```
data <- read.csv("Vendor_Data.csv")
```

Comment: You must use double backslashes. Or single `/`.

Comment: Yup . That worked . Thanks Jonny & Rui .